# how to branch locally from remote branch using git

Tags: git, github, branch

I have remote `origin` with branches `a`, `b`

and local branch `a`.

I have finished working on local-a, and pushed it to remote-a.

I now want to create a local branch `b-myUserName` based on remote `b`.

How do I do this?

**Update**

after trying to branch a remote branch to my workplace,

I get the following error:

```
**$ git checkout -b canc_el --track origin/canc**
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    src/iphone/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers
    src/iphone/FacebookSDK.framework/Resources
    src/iphone/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/Current
    src/iphone/Xcode/Crashlytics.framework/Headers

Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

That's strange. I haven't removed them from tracking.

I want them to be overriden. I know nothing much about them.

What should I do?

Comment: The question seems to have changed now. Just a `git checkout origin/canc` would cause the problem. There's more than one possible cause; maybe the files have been added to `origin/canc` but were not tracked in the previous branch. The solution depends on the situation - the safest is `git add` and commit the files, and proceed after that, after which they're tracked in your private "a" branch (or, like sometimes I have done, the contents have no important changes and I have simply removed them. Obviously requires knowing that nothing important really does not get wiped).

Comment: if i back hem aside. then remove them and finally checkout. how can I apply this on folders? (they are all folders) Will it work? They are all folders.. which is strange. Their inner files are not lister in the `untracked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> git checkout -b b-myUserName --track origin/b

or split to two commands:

```
git checkout origin/b
git checkout -b b-myUserName
```

Comment: what does `--track remotes/b` mean?

Comment: @EladBenda Sorry, meant "origin" (assuming the remote goes by that name)

Comment: Sets the upstream branch. That's a bit redundant since it's the default for remote branches, but I like to be explicit.

Comment: is it `git checkout -b` or `git branch -b` ?

Comment: @EladBenda `checkout -b`. That's a shortcut for creating a branch and checking it out (so the second line could be split further to `git branch -f b-myUserName` and `git checkout b-myUserName`). `checkout -b` is usually what you want to do.

Comment: thanks, I had another difficulty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212192/the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by