# The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by

Tags: java, git, version-control, git-branch

after trying to branch a remote branch to my workplace,

I get the following error:

```
**$ git checkout -b canc_el --track origin/canc**
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    src/iphone/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers
    src/iphone/FacebookSDK.framework/Resources
    src/iphone/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/Current
    src/iphone/Xcode/Crashlytics.framework/Headers

Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

That's strange. I haven't removed them from tracking.

I want them to be overriden. I know nothing much about them.

What should I do?

**Update**

I have tried to remove and checkout these folders and got this error:

```
    $ git rm src/iphone/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers
fatal: pathspec 'src/iphone/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers' did not match any files

    $ git checkout src/iphone/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers
    error: pathspec 'src/iphone/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems those files aren't tracked in your current branch, but are on `origin/canc`.

The simplest thing to do is just `rm` them and then `checkout`. If you want to be more cautious, `add` and `stash` them, or backup them in any way.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. `git status --short` should list them as untracked, or `git clean -ndX` should list them as ignored, and `git diff --name-status origin/canc HEAD` should list them too.

Comment: Yes, I emphasize : before removing them, check your `git status`

Comment: `add and stash them` but it will cause a merge conflict. no? I want the remote version (theirs) anyway...

Comment: There may be conflicts when you un`stash` them, yes. But I was thinking of `stash`ing them, use the `origin/canc` branch, then go back to your current branch and then un`stash` them in the same branch you `stash`ed it - that way you won't have conflicts.